# Exit only 1 for loop and not the other

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I'm looping all page break in my worksheet. I have a for loop inside another for loop. When my condition is met, I want to exit the inner loop only, but why is my code exiting both loop when there is still more break page to loop? Here is what I have:

```
FoundRange = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

getLastRow = FoundRange
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ("$A$1:$Q$" & getLastRow + 500) '*** Need to increase my printarea to accomodate all the pagebreak i was setting along the way, changed to 1000 and it works.
For Each pb In ws.HPageBreaks
    For i = pb.Location.Row To 17 Step -1
        if i - getLastRow < 14 then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Cells(getLastRow + 1, 1)
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            exit for 'also tried goto Here
        end if
    next
'Here:
next '<< gets here on exit for, but it doesn't loop my next page break. Acts like it is the last page break when I know there is more.
```

Comment: Odd, I thought the default behavior was to exit only one... maybe someone else has insight.

Comment: An `Exit For` should only kick you out the `For` loop in which it is called. I suspect something else is causing the issue here. Put the command `Stop` after the `next` for your nested for and see if it's hit. I suspect it will be.

Comment: @JNevill looks like it does get to the Next but it doesn't loop my next page break and goes out of the outer loop.

Comment: Right. So I think the issue is that it's not iterating your page breaks. I suspect you only have 1 to start with and only add them in your inner loop, but because the `pb` loop was initialized before that existed, you only get the 1 loop. Totally guessing here as I've never iterated `HPageBreaks` before and I've never tried adding to members to the collection on which I'm looping to extend the loop. It seems a little odd... like what are you really wanting to do here.

Comment: Yah I think my answer was wrong, you did have a For...Next loop. Forget the inner loop and just see if you can make it iterate through page breaks.

Comment: I edited my post, found out i ran out of page breaks to loop since i was setting page break as i went as well. I needed to increase my print area therefore i would have enough page break to loop and do my conditions.